# I need to override admin login page in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I need to access the magento2 admin login page using my custom module.How can i override login.phtml into my custom template file like custom-login.phtml file.

Kindly check the below coding and give me some solutions,

Check the layout file **view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_auth_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="admin.login">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::admin/login.phtml</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

In my custom module added that xml file and placed the login.phtml in my custom module. The file path was **view/adminhtml/templates/admin/login.phtml**.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following layout update to set template.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="admin.login">
   <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::admin/login.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: Am already tried this method,on that time it was not worked.Surprisingly now its works.Thanks for your help 
**Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.**